# Create vertical line by calculating length of a text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-spacing, rules

Line 1: "Someeeeeeeee Textttttttttttt" (custom font is used, italics,font size say 24)
vspace(10mm)

Line 2: "Someeee Textttt" This should be centered below line one wrt to text above.

vspace(10mm)

Line 3: Want a HoriZontal line here, with predefined color and thickness. just like an underline
The size of Line 2 object (the vertical line) should be like 40% of the length of text in Line2

ie Output:

[Someeeeeeeee Textttttttttttt]

vspace(10mm)

[Someeee Textttt] <- this will be centered below text in line one

vspace(10mm)

________ <- this line should be 40% of the length of [Someeee Textttttt] and be centered w.r.t of the text above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing between horizontal and vertical.

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newlength{\titlerulewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{24}{30}\itshape
Someeeeeeeee Textttttttttttt

\vspace{10mm}

\fontsize{18}{24}\itshape
\settowidth{\titlerulewidth}{Someeee Textttt}

Someeee Textttt

\vspace{10mm}

\rule{0.4\titlerulewidth}{2pt}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. i need this to work inside a minipage environment which is inside a table cell. will test and post any glitches. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

EDITED to turn process into a macro.  I also added a `\strut` so that the presence of descenders does not alter the depth of the underset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \savebox\tmpbox{\Huge\strut#1}%
  \stackunder[10mm]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}{\textcolor{red}{\rule{5pt}{.4\wd\tmpbox}}}
}
\begin{document}
\foo{Some Text} and \foo{My Longer Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the desire was for a horizontal line, then the fix to the above code is simple... reverese the `\rule` arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \savebox\tmpbox{\Huge\strut#1}%
  \stackunder[10mm]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}{\textcolor{red}{\rule{.4\wd\tmpbox}{5pt}}}
}
\begin{document}
\foo{Some Text} and \foo{My Longer Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]